# The "Auto Fib Retracement" indicator written by TradingView: follows the highest of each bar?

Tags: pine-script

According to the indicator "Retracement Auto Fib" written by TradingView, do you know how to make fibo 0 follow the highest of each bar?

```
import TradingView/ZigZag/6 as zigzag

update()=>
    var settings = zigzag.Settings.new(threshold_multiplier, depth, color(na), false, false, false, false, "Absolute", true)
    var zigzag.ZigZag zigZag = zigzag.newInstance(settings)
    var zigzag.Pivot lastP = na
    var float startPrice = na
    var float height = na
    settings.devThreshold := ta.atr(10) / close * 100 * threshold_multiplier
    if zigZag.update()
        lastP := zigZag.lastPivot()
        if not na(lastP)
            var line lineLast = na
            if na(lineLast)
                lineLast := line.new(lastP.start.tm, lastP.start.price, lastP.end.tm, lastP.end.price, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.gray, width=1, style=line.style_dashed)
            else
                line.set_xy1(lineLast, lastP.start.tm, lastP.start.price)
                line.set_xy2(lineLast, lastP.end.tm, lastP.end.price)

            startPrice := reverse ? lastP.start.price : lastP.end.price
            endPrice = reverse ? lastP.end.price : lastP.start.price
            height := (startPrice > endPrice ? -1 : 1) * math.abs(startPrice - endPrice)
    [lastP, startPrice, height]

[lastP, startPrice, height] = update()

_draw_line(price, col) =>
    var id = line.new(lastP.start.tm, lastP.start.price, time, price, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=col, width=1, extend=extend.none)
    line.set_xy1(id, lastP.start.tm, price)
    line.set_xy2(id, time, price)
    id
```